# How to Add Multiple Filters in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have this code that converts input fields with a specific CSS class into a read-only field. The code is working well but what's the best practice to add a second form into the filter without copying and pasting the entire code again?

```
// ID of the Form
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_138', 'add_readonly_script' );
function add_readonly_script( $form ) {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).on('gform_post_render', function(){

            /* apply only to a input with a class of gf_readonly */
            jQuery(".gf_readonly input").attr("readonly","readonly");
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to duplicate all the code. I´m inferring that this piece of code come from somewhere in WordPress with Google Forms seems.

The only thing you have to do is apply filter to the other form too.

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_my_second_form_id', 'add_readonly_script' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_138', 'add_readonly_script' );
function add_readonly_script( $form ) {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).on('gform_post_render', function(){

            /* apply only to a input with a class of gf_readonly */
            jQuery(".gf_readonly input").attr("readonly","readonly");
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    return $form;
}
```

Comment: This code is for Gravity Form and your solution is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!